# Create a directory in Perl outside of bin folder

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a folder in perl but it either appears in the C:\ drive or the folder where my perl script is located.

```
 use File::Basename;
 use File::Path qw/make_path/;

 my $file = "/$tournamentName/files/archive/";
 my $dir = dirname($file);
 make_path($dir);
```

The above code places the $tournamentName folder in the C:\ drive. How can I specify that the folder is created outside of bin - preferably in the parent folder of bin.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $dir = "$path_to_bin/../$tournamentName";
```

If you mean the directory in which the script is located,

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

my $dir = "$RealBin/../$tournamentName";
```